# Philips hue, convert xy from api to HEX or RGB

Tags: javascript, philips-hue

I am making a web interface to manage my hue lamps, but i am struggling when it comes to color handling..

The api of the lamps provides me the x and y coordinates from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space

But not the z value.

I think i must calculate the z from the brightness value or saturation value  (0 to 255).

but i am terrible at colors, and math :p.

I tried to use thoses functions https://github.com/eikeon/hue-color-converter/blob/master/colorconverter.ts

But as i saw in the comments, thoses functions do not provide correct values...

Could someone help me here please ? ☺

ps : i need a javascript function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay so i manage to make something working with the help of : [How do I convert an RGB value to a XY value for the Phillips Hue Bulb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854825/how-do-i-convert-an-rgb-value-to-a-xy-value-for-the-phillips-hue-bulb)

```
function xyBriToRgb(x, y, bri){
            z = 1.0 - x - y;
            Y = bri / 255.0; // Brightness of lamp
            X = (Y / y) * x;
            Z = (Y / y) * z;
            r = X * 1.612 - Y * 0.203 - Z * 0.302;
            g = -X * 0.509 + Y * 1.412 + Z * 0.066;
            b = X * 0.026 - Y * 0.072 + Z * 0.962;
            r = r <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * r : (1.0 + 0.055) * Math.pow(r, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
            g = g <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * g : (1.0 + 0.055) * Math.pow(g, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
            b = b <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * b : (1.0 + 0.055) * Math.pow(b, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
            maxValue = Math.max(r,g,b);
            r /= maxValue;
            g /= maxValue;
            b /= maxValue;
            r = r * 255;   if (r < 0) { r = 255 };
            g = g * 255;   if (g < 0) { g = 255 };
            b = b * 255;   if (b < 0) { b = 255 };
            return {
                r :r,
                g :g,
                b :b
            }
        }
```

Its not very very precise, but it works quite well. If someone manage to make something better, please post it here, thanks.

Comment: Did you figure out how to go back the other way?

Comment: Very late to the party, but to go back the other way you can use https://github.com/q42philips/hue-color-converter

Answer (score 7):

I modified your script to return the rgb value in HEX Notation:

```
function xyBriToRgb(x, y, bri)
{
    z = 1.0 - x - y;

    Y = bri / 255.0; // Brightness of lamp
    X = (Y / y) * x;
    Z = (Y / y) * z;
    r = X * 1.612 - Y * 0.203 - Z * 0.302;
    g = -X * 0.509 + Y * 1.412 + Z * 0.066;
    b = X * 0.026 - Y * 0.072 + Z * 0.962;
    r = r <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * r : (1.0 + 0.055) * Math.pow(r, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
    g = g <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * g : (1.0 + 0.055) * Math.pow(g, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
    b = b <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * b : (1.0 + 0.055) * Math.pow(b, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
    maxValue = Math.max(r,g,b);
    r /= maxValue;
    g /= maxValue;
    b /= maxValue;
    r = r * 255;   if (r < 0) { r = 255 };
    g = g * 255;   if (g < 0) { g = 255 };
    b = b * 255;   if (b < 0) { b = 255 };

    r = Math.round(r).toString(16);
    g = Math.round(g).toString(16);
    b = Math.round(b).toString(16);

    if (r.length < 2)
        r="0"+r;        
    if (g.length < 2)
        g="0"+g;        
    if (b.length < 2)
        b="0"+r;        
    rgb = "#"+r+g+b;

    return rgb;             
}
alert(xyBriToRgb(0.5052,0.4151, 254));
```

And i made a PHP Version:

```
function xyBriToRgb($x,$y,$bri)
{
    $z = 1.0 - $x - $y;
    $Y = $bri / 255.0;
    $X = ($Y / $y) * $x;
    $Z = ($Y / $y) * $z;

    $r = $X * 1.612 - $Y * 0.203 - $Z * 0.302;
    $g = ($X * -1) * 0.509 + $Y * 1.412 + $Z * 0.066;
    $b = $X * 0.026 - $Y * 0.072 + $Z * 0.962;

    $r = $r <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * $r : (1.0 + 0.055) * pow($r, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
    $g = $g <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * $g : (1.0 + 0.055) * pow($g, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;
    $b = $b <= 0.0031308 ? 12.92 * $b : (1.0 + 0.055) * pow($b, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055;

    $maxValue = max( $r , $g, $b );

    $r = $r / $maxValue;
    $g = $g / $maxValue;
    $b = $b / $maxValue;

    $r = $r * 255; if ($r < 0) $r = 255;
    $g = $g * 255; if ($g < 0) $g = 255;
    $b = $b * 255; if ($b < 0) $b = 255;

    $r = dechex(round($r));
    $g = dechex(round($g));
    $b = dechex(round($b));

    if (strlen($r) < 2)     $r = "0" + $r;
    if (strlen($g) < 2)     $g = "0" + $g;
    if (strlen($b) < 2)     $b = "0" + $b;

    return "#".$r.$g.$b;
}
print xyBriToRgb(0.5052,0.4151, 254);
```

Happy coding to ye all :-)

Answer (score 2):

At the end it should probably be

```
r = Math.round(r * 255); if (r < 0) { r = 0; }
g = Math.round(g * 255); if (g < 0) { g = 0; }
b = Math.round(b * 255); if (b < 0) { b = 0; }
```

If `r`,`g` or `b` is smaller than 0, shouldn't it be 0 instead of 255? The colors I tested make more sense that way.
Thanks for the formula though!